# What Is The Initial Value of Stack Pointer of 8086 (x86-16) CPU?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, boot, stack-pointer

1. What is the initial value of SS, SP, BP? Are they null (0x0) or for example does SP immediately set to 0xFFFE?
2. When we write an assembly code without using pop and push statements does stack pointer set to a value?

Comment: What's "initial"?  Do you mean immediately after CPU reset, or something else?

Comment: I mean CPU reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the original 8086, see [The 8086 Family Users Manual](http://bitsavers.org/components/intel/8086/9800722-03_The_8086_Family_Users_Manual_Oct79.pdf).  Table 2-4 defines "CPU State Following RESET"; it shows that SS is set to 0000H.  The state of general-purpose registers including SP and BP is not documented, so presumably the programmer is supposed to consider them undefined and initialize them manually.

For recent CPUs, see Intel's [Software Developer's Manual, Volume 3A](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html).  Table 9-1 defines Processor State After Reset.  SS is set to 0000H, with a base address of 00000000H, limit of FFFFH, access rights of Present, R/W, Accessed.  EBP and ESP are set to 00000000H.

If you do not write any instructions that modify the stack pointer, it does not change.

Comment: Keep in mind this is specific to this CPU. Other CPUs such as the Motorola 68000 have a predefined value in their program header that they load the initial value of SP from.

Comment: @puppydrum64 See comment by OP to question, it is about state after reset before running of the operating system, which could read the program header. Or can the 68000 directly read the (initial) program header with special pins or signals?

Comment: @Sebastian I believe so since even on machines with no BIOS (like the Sega Genesis) your stack pointer is already set up without you having to write any code to set it. Sort of like how the 6502 effectively executes a `JMP ($FFFC)` upon startup

Comment: @puppydrum64 Sure, a default value. But reading from an externally stored program header even before code execution starts just seems unlikely, although possible.